# Duplicate data name from base class in python

Tags: python, oop, namespaces

```
class A:
    def __init__(self):
        self.num = 1

class B(A):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.num = 2
```

What happened here and Can I use the num data in instance A?

I can do the following in C++:

```cpp
n = B(); n::A.num
```

Comment: You are setting attributes on the _instance_, not on the class. The instance attribute namespace is flat, and has no class-specific names (outside of the `__name` convention, which explicitly renames attributes to prefix them with the class name).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are confusing instances with classes here.

The `self` reference in the `__init__` method is the current instance object, and the statement `self.num = ...` sets the attribute `num` on that instance. There is no distinction as to what code sets that attribute, so there is no distinction between the `A.__init__()` method and the `B.__init__()` method setting the attribute.

In other words: the `self.num = 2` statement, having run last, wins. The value `1` set in `A.__init__()` is overwritten.

There is an exception to this; when you use [names that start with a double underscore](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#reserved-classes-of-identifiers) (but not end with a double underscore), then those names are *automatically rewritten* to include the current class as a prefix. From the [*Identifiers (Names)* section of the expression reference documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#atom-identifiers):

> **Private name mangling**: When an identifier that textually occurs in a class definition begins with two or more underscore characters and does not end in two or more underscores, it is considered a private name of that class. Private names are transformed to a longer form before code is generated for them. The transformation inserts the class name, with leading underscores removed and a single underscore inserted, in front of the name. For example, the identifier `__spam` occurring in a class named `Ham` will be transformed to `_Ham__spam`.

So if you used:

```py
class A:
    def __init__(self):
        self.__num = 1

class B(A):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.__num = 2
```

then an instance `b = B()` will have two attributes, `b._A__num` and `b._B__num` that are separate and distinct. The aim of this feature is to give each class a separate namespace that won't (easily) be interfered with by subclasses.

Demo of the latter:

```py
>>> class A:
...     def __init__(self):
...         self.__num = 1
...
>>> class B(A):
...     def __init__(self):
...         super().__init__()
...         self.__num = 2
...
>>> b = B()
>>> vars(b)
{'_A__num': 1, '_B__num': 2}
>>> b._A__num
1
```